# Azure Data Factory - Degree of copy parallelism

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm running an Azure Data Factory that copies multiple tables from on prem SQL server to an Azure Data Lake.

So, I set many Copy activities through Az Data Factory Designer to execute parallel copies (each activity is carrying on the extract of one table).

For better resources optimization, I would like to know if there is a way to copy multiple tables with one Copy activity ?

I heard of "degree of copy parallelism", but don't know how to use it ?

Rgds,

---

**If the question helped, up-vote it. Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use one Copy activity for multiple tables, you'd need to wrap a single parameterized Copy activity in a ForEach activity.  The ForEach can scale to run multiple sources at one time by setting isSequential to false and setting the batchCount value to the number of threads you want.  The default batch count is 20 and the max is 50.  Copy Parallelism on a single Copy activity just uses more threads to concurrently copy partitions of data from the same data source.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your explanation on Copy Parallelism and single table partitions. I was confused as I mixed it with multiple tables copies.... Best Regards.